# AWS EKS LoadBalancer DNS not responding

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I created EKS cluster on AWS eks with delpoyment and manifest for simple NestJS app
Docker image is working properly when pulled from ECR, as well in local environment.
But when i deploy Loadbalancer is not aplicable. All security groups  and VPC are provided default by eksctl

Here is my Deployment manifest

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: techcare-deployment-apigw-v3  # Modified name reflecting the new version
  namespace: techcare
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: techcare-deployment-apigw-v3   # Updated label for the selector
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: techcare-deployment-apigw-v3   # Updated label for the pod template
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: techcare-deployment-apigw-v3
          image: 435109652403.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/api-gateway:1.0.49
          env:
            - name: TEST_URL
              value: "192.168.69.78:10008"
            - name: PORT
              value: "3000"

          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
              name: apigw-port
```

Here is my Service manifest

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: techcare-service-apigw-v3
  name: techcare-service-apigw-v3
  namespace: techcare
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 3000  # Replace this with the actual port number your app is listening on
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 3000  # Replace this with the actual port number your app is listening on
  selector:
    app: techcare-deployment-apigw-v3   # Updated to match the correct deployment
```

Logs from deployed pod

```
kubectl logs  techcare-deployment-apigw-v3-7b55b6b498-rwzv4 -n techcare                                                                                                                                    ✔  nbozic@techcare-1.eu-central-1.eksctl.io ○  01:27:38  
[Nest] 1  - 12/07/2023, 12:28:09 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 1  - 12/07/2023, 12:28:09 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +210ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/07/2023, 12:28:09 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] TestGrpcModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/07/2023, 12:28:09 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/07/2023, 12:28:09 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/07/2023, 12:28:10 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +4ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/07/2023, 12:28:10 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/health, GET} route +5ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/07/2023, 12:28:10 PM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +9ms
API gateway is running on:  3000
```

and here are the logs from service

```
kubectl describe service techcare-service-apigw-v3 -n techcare                                                                                                                                             ✔  nbozic@techcare-1.eu-central-1.eksctl.io ○  01:19:59  
Name:                     techcare-service-apigw-v3
Namespace:                techcare
Labels:                   app=techcare-service-apigw-v3
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=techcare-deployment-apigw-v3
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.100.159.32
IPs:                      10.100.159.32
LoadBalancer Ingress:     aa53456dd1fa04c1d9b5775ab85bbaa5-424417597.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               3000/TCP
NodePort:                 http  31439/TCP
Endpoints:                
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               3000/TCP
NodePort:                 https  31008/TCP
Endpoints:                
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age   From                Message
  ----    ------                ----  ----                -------
  Normal  EnsuringLoadBalancer  89s   service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
  Normal  EnsuredLoadBalancer   86s   service-controller  Ensured load balancer
```

when i try to get response  from `https://aa53456dd1fa04c1d9b5775ab85bbaa5-424417597.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com/health` I cannot reach

[image]

I also tried with Load balance controller following this steps
https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/deploy/installation/

and try to apply

````
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: techcare-alb
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    spec.ingressClassName: alb
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: techcare-service-apigw-v3
                port:
                  number: 80
``` but same no traffic
````